# What's the correct markup for stacked fontawesome icons as a bulleted list?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to use fontawesome icons in a bulleted list. The guide provides the markup below:

```
<ul class="icons-ul">
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Bulleted lists (like this one)</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Buttons</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Button groups</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Navigation</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Prepended form inputs</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>&hellip;and many more with custom CSS</li>
</ul>
```

Simples. Eh? However, instead of plain old icons, I want to use a font awesome stack. Comme ca:

```
<span class="icon-stack">
  <i class="icon-check-empty icon-stack-base"></i>
  <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
</span>
```

Question is; how can I combine the two? Sticking `icon-li` in the stack span class doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
  <ul class="icons-ul">

    <li>
      <span class="icon-stack icon-li">
        <i class="icon-check-empty icon-stack-base"></i>
        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
      </span>
      Buttons
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="icon-stack icon-li">
        <i class="icon-check-empty icon-stack-base"></i>
        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
      </span>
      …and many more with custom CSS
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the newer version of font awesome (4.0.3), you can use bootstrap's list-unstyled class to get the same effect.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <span class="fa-stack">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue. I want to use a stacked icon as a bullet for a `li`. More than this, I've been trying to *combine* stacked and normal icons in the same `ul` which has proven to be a nightmare.

I managed to solve the problem, sort of. I'm building a new site, [busycreator.com](http://busycreator.com), and if you visit you will see the second column in the footer which has social media links. The Dribbble icon is actually a stack (the Dribbble logo and a solid circle). Here's what I did:

```
<ul class="fa-ul" style="margin-left:21px;">
    <li style="margin-bottom:6px;">
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-pinterest-square fa-lg" style="color:#c40f2d;"></i>
            <a href="#" title="Pinterest">pinterest</a>
    </li>
<li class="fa-stack">
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-circle fa-lg" style="color:#e2418a;"></i>
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-dribbble fa-lg" style="color:#be0f64;"></i>
            <a style="position:relative; top:-3px;" href="#" title="Dribbble">dribbble#</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, there's a fair amount of inline styling, which is never idea. There's some manual positioning using margins/padding AND relative positioning, but this is the only thing that worked. I have the feeling that a number of external style sheets competing with one another, so inline styling is the only way I managed to get it to work.

There's one side effect which is that the link name — the stuff between `<a>` and `</a>` —cannot contain a space. Otherwise, each word will break onto its own line, forming a list within a list.

Feel free to build on this silliness and get it to work properly. I'll be grateful.